# RefreshToken from Passport Google Strategy OAUTH2.0 is undefined? Express.js

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

In my passport strategy I retrieve my accessToken and refreshToken from my OAUTH2 strategy. It was working fine just the other day and now for no discernable reason, refreshToken is undefined.

I can't find anything about the refreshToken in the documentation. If I wipe my cache/cookies on browser it works once. After that it's back to undefined. (I also reset my OAUTH settings with new clientId in google cloud console)

I don't know why.

**My passport.js file: **

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
            refreshToken: true, //this should get a refreshToken
        },
        function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            // This function is called after the user grants permission and the authorization code is exchanged for an access token
            console.log("Myprofile: ", profile);
            console.log("REFRESHTOKEN: ", refreshToken); //undefined here
            done(null, { profile, accessToken, refreshToken });
        }
    )
);
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("myPre user: ", user);
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("my user: ", user);
    done(null, user);
});
```

**My Auth.js file: **

```
router.get(
    "/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
        scope: ["profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"],
        accessType: "offline",
        approvalPrompt: "force",
    })
); //this navigates to the consent screen to
//get code from user profile

//Call passport.authenticate again(now with code after consent screen) and obtain profile data(and accessToken)
router.get(
    "/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/auth/error" }),
    function (req, res) {
        //console.log(req.user);
        //console.log("MY TOKEN: ", req.user.accessToken);
        //console.log("accessing accessToken in callback!...going to redirect to forntend now");
        //const accessToken = req.user.accessToken;
        //res.cookie("accessToken", accessToken);
        // This function is called after the user grants permission and the authorization code is exchanged for an access token
        res.redirect("http://localhost:8080/auth/success");
        //res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/Project/YoutubeApp/Home");
    }
);
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/27#issuecomment-313969184

It didn't help me though :(